# WPF XmlNodeList how to SelectNodes with multiple same element nodes and attributes?

Tags: c#, xpath, selectnodes

I need to make 2 xPath(s) where it displays the Procedure's description:

- IF EVERY Step finished is equal to "True"
- If only one of Step finished is true.

**XML File:**

```
<Procedures>
    <Procedure>
        <description>Work1</description>
        <Steps>
            <Step finished="False" no="1">Step1</etape>
            <Step finished="False" no="2">Step2</etape>
            <Step finished="False" no="4">Step3</etape>
            <Step finished="True" no="5">Step4</etape>
            
        </Steps>
    </Procedure>
    </Procedures>
```

**What I've tried:**

- Expected to see the procedure's description if every step finished is equal to True but it does not work.
  `XmlNodeList testList = doc.SelectNodes("//Procedure/description[//Step/@finished='True']");`

Answer (score 0):

These are the two approaches:

1. EVERY Step finished is equal to "True"

   ```
   /Procedures/Procedure/Steps[count(Step)=count(Step[@finished='True'])]/../description
   ```
2. ONLY one of Step finished is "True"

   ```
   /Procedures/Procedure/Steps[Step/@finished='True']/../description
   ```

Of course `/Procedures/Procedure...` can be replaced by `//Procedure...`.

Answer (score 0):

At least on Step with finished being True: `//Procedure[Steps/Step/@finished = 'True']/description`.

No Step with finished being False: `//Procedure[not(Steps/Step/@finished = 'False')]/description`.